# How to disable @assert in Julia

Tags: julia, assert

As an old C programmer, I use lots of asserts in my code.  Now I want to globally switch them off to speed things up.  What is the best practice way to do that?

Comment: This is really something that should be added, but there's no flag for this currently.

Answer (score 14):

There is no built-in option / command line flag to disable `@assert`s globally, yet(!).

For now, you can define a `@myassert` macro which, depending on a global switch, is a no-op or a regular `@assert`:

```
asserting() = false # when set to true, this will enable all `@myassert`s

macro mayassert(test)
  esc(:(if $(@__MODULE__).asserting()
    @assert($test)
   end))
end

f(x) = @mayassert x < 2
```

(taken from https://discourse.julialang.org/t/assert-alternatives/24775/14)

Answer (score 3):

You could put your `@assert` statements in a `@debug` block. Then the `@assert` call is desactivated, unless you activate debugging either globally (`ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "all"`) or just for your module (`ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "NameOfYourModule"`)

```
julia> @debug begin
          @assert 1==2
       end
       #or 
       @debug @assert 1==2 # assert is not called

julia> ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "all" # enable debugging
"all"

julia> @debug begin
          @assert 1==2
       end
┌ Error: Exception while generating log record in module Main at REPL[4]:1
│   exception =
│    AssertionError: 1 == 2
│    Stacktrace:
│     [1] top-level scope at REPL[4]:2
│     [2] top-level scope at logging.jl:319
|     ...
└ @ Main REPL[4]:1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, violation of the assertion no longer leads to program termination, but rather the log message `Error: Exception while generating log record in module`.